# HTML creating a button that links to another website within a table

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, html-table

I want to create a button within a table I have on my web page called "Join". This button should take the user to another page like: http://localhost:3000. However, I have not been able to create a button within the table that is successfully able to redirect me to the desired page when clicking on it.

Below is my code for two button I have on my website which works successfully and it shows the format I follow to incorporate the buttons into the table.

My code:

```
echo "<table>
   <tr>
   <th>Update</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>";
   while(...(...)){
   echo "<form action=findGroup.php method=post>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=submit name=update value='Update" . "'/> </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=submit name=delete value='Delete" . "'/> </td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code out. I just wrapped buttons with `<a href=""></a>` tags. There you can put your link where you want to navigate by clicking the buttons. I also escaped quotation marks.

```
echo "<table>
   <tr>
   <th>Update</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>";
   while(){
   echo "<form action=\"findGroup.php\" method=\"post\">";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" ."<a href=\"localhost\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"update\" value=\"Update\" /> </td></a>";
   echo "<td>" ."<a href=\"localhost\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" /> </td></a>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks, however, the button does not work when clicking on it to take me to my desired page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two versions:
1 If you want to keep browsing history you could use window.location = "url"
2 If you don't want to keep browsing history you could use window.location.replace("url")

Thus your code could be something like this.

```php
echo "<table>
   <tr>
   <th>Update</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>";
   while(...(...)){
   echo "<form action=findGroup.php method=post>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td> <input type=submit name=update value='Update' onclick='window.location=\"http://yourupdateURL.com\";'/> </td>";
   echo "<td> <input type=submit name=delete value='Delete' onclick='window.location = \"http://YourDeleteURL.com\" ;'/> </td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

OR

```php
echo "<table>
   <tr>
   <th>Update</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>";
   while(...(...)){
   echo "<form action=findGroup.php method=post>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td> <input type=submit name=update value='Update' onclick='window.location.replace(\"http://yourupdateURL.com\");'/> </td>";
   echo "<td> <input type=submit name=delete value='Delete' onclick='window.location.replace(\"http://YourDeleteURL.com\") ;'/> </td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

You don't really need a form for that unless you wanted to send data to that page. Then you should take some other considerations.

On the othe hand, taking into account what you just posted in comments you can do something like this:

- Add id property to your form.
- Change your input type to button, otherwise it will  submit your form no matter you are putting in the onclick property.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function sendFormToLocation(id,url){
 //Get your form
 var form = document.getElementById(id);
 
 // Do your code stuff, encode your data, submit your form data via ajax, etc
 //...
 
 //Finally go to your desired location
 window.location=url;
}
</script>


<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Update</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
 </tr>
   
 <form action=findGroup.php method=post id="XXX">
  <tr>
   <td> <input type=button name=update value='Update' onclick='sendFormToLocation("XXX", "http://yourupdateURL.com")'/> </td>
   <td> <input type=button name=delete value='Delete' onclick='sendFormToLocation("XXX", "http://YourDeleteURL.com")'/> </td>
  </tr>
 </form>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, the button is perfect, only problem is it does not go anywhere when clicking it for both of the statements you have above. Also, I'm using a form to send data to my database when users update a table or delete.

Comment: That's because you are using a submit button, you maybe need to be more clear on what do you want to do, so one can give you some advice.